# How to split number and list into sublist in python

Tags: python, list, split, numbers

i have a variable **num**, there are bunch of number on the list

```py
num = [1273849173948576379, 7483946582903647829]
```

how to split it into two separate number and sub list like this:

```py
[[12,73,84..],[74,83,94..]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be

```
[[int(str(j)[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(str(j)), 2)] for j in num]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the same thing using re would be:

```
num = [1273849173948576379, 7483946582903647829]
import re
print([list(map(int, re.findall('..?', str(x)))) for x in num])
```

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension method would be more efficient, however the naive way to do would be:

```
num = [1273849173948576379, 7483946582903647829]
new_list = []

for number in num:
    # Converting each number into string so that we can slice using index
    str_number = str(number)

    # Empty list for storing pieces of each number in num 
    tmp = []

    # Using for loop to increment from start i.e. 0 till < length of string 
    # and each time increment is by 2
    for i in range(0, len(str_number), 2):

        # Slicing the index to get two digit number and appending to tmp
        int_number = str_number[i:i+2]
        tmp.append(int(int_number))

    # Finally done with one of the number in num so, appending to new_list
    new_list.append(tmp)

new_list
```

Output:

```
[[12, 73, 84, 91, 73, 94, 85, 76, 37, 9],
 [74, 83, 94, 65, 82, 90, 36, 47, 82, 9]]
```